# Windows 10 lock screen login loop

Tags: windows-10

On my win 10 machine, I am stuck in a login loop after I lock my screen overnight.

After I type in my password, the circle will spin and after a while go back to the password input screen again. (rinse and repeat)

To use my computer, I need to restart and then I can login. Anyone have the same experience?

winver = 1607 (OS Build 14393.187)

Comment: This problem went away with a newer build of Win 10.

Answer (score 0):

I had to unplug my USB wireless keyboard, mouse and disconnect WiFi, completely shutdown. Started back up and then it worked. (Laptop)

Comment: OP says restarting already allows them to login again.